# JavaFX cannot load image from resource folder

Tags: java, javafx, java-14

I have been working on a **JavaFX** project with **Maven**. I am using **JDK 14** with **IntelliJ** IDE to compile my project into a **JAR** artifact.

I have linked the **CSS** files into **FXML** through **Scene Builder**. The CSS files contain necessary background image information.

The program runs perfectly inside the IDE. But it is showing the following error when I run as a JAR.

```
Error loading image: jar:file:/C:/Users/Sajed/Desktop/GitHub/IFTAS/out/artifacts/IFTAS_jar/IFTAS.jar!/tgtList/main.jpg
```

My project structure is like the following:

```
src  
  -main  
    -java  
      -tgtList
        -Java File
    -resources
      -tgtList
        -FXML file
        -main.jpg
        -backgorund.css
```

Can someone point me out the possible areas I should be concerned with?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sajed</groupId>
    <artifactId>IFTA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.32.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.13</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>16-ea+4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>16-ea+4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>16-ea+4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>16-ea+4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**background.css**

```
.mainbg{
   -fx-background-image: url('main.jpg');
   -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;    
}
```

**Tgt.fxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="600.0" minWidth="800.0" styleClass="mainbg" stylesheets="@background.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tgtList.TgtController">
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="id" prefWidth="50.0" text="Id" visible="false" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="ser" prefWidth="50.0" text="Ser" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="tgtName" prefWidth="190.0" text="Name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="tgtSize" prefWidth="150.0" text="Size" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="tgtPosture" prefWidth="180.0" text="Posture" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="terr" prefWidth="115.0" text="Terr" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
    <top>
        <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <JFXComboBox fx:id="fieldTgtSize" promptText="Select" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <Label text="Tgt Size" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="20.0" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="TGT ASSESSMENT" underline="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <JFXButton fx:id="add" buttonType="RAISED" onAction="#add" style="-fx-background-color: green;" text="Add" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="20.0" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </JFXButton>
                <Label text="Posture" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="20.0" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <JFXComboBox fx:id="fieldPosture" focusColor="#4ca128" promptText="Select" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                <Label text="Tgt Name" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="20.0" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <JFXTextField fx:id="fieldTgtName" focusColor="#4ca128" promptText="Write Tgt Name" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets right="30.0" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                </JFXTextField>
                <Label text="Terr" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets left="20.0" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <JFXComboBox fx:id="fieldTerr" focusColor="#4ca128" promptText="Select" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                <JFXButton fx:id="delete" buttonType="RAISED" onAction="#deleteFromDb" style="-fx-background-color: red;" text="Delete" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </JFXButton>
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

**TgtController.java**

```
package tgtList;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import constants.IConstants;
import database.TgtDB;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import model.TgtModel;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TgtController implements Initializable {

    private static final TgtDB tgtDb = new TgtDB();
    ObservableList<TgtModel> obs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    TableView<TgtModel> tableView;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TgtModel, String> id = new TableColumn<>();
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TgtModel, String> ser = new TableColumn<>();
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TgtModel, String> tgtName = new TableColumn<>();
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TgtModel, String> tgtSize = new TableColumn<>();
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TgtModel, String> tgtPosture = new TableColumn<>();
    @FXML
    TableColumn<TgtModel, String> terr = new TableColumn<>();

    @FXML
    JFXTextField fieldTgtName = new JFXTextField();
    @FXML
    JFXComboBox<Label> fieldTgtSize = new JFXComboBox<>();
    @FXML
    JFXComboBox<Label> fieldPosture = new JFXComboBox<>();
    @FXML
    JFXComboBox<Label> fieldTerr = new JFXComboBox<>();

    @FXML
    JFXButton add;
    @FXML
    JFXButton delete;

    private static void getErrorPopUp() {

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setHeaderText("Duplicate Tgt Name");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        fieldTgtSize.getItems().addAll(Arrays.stream(IConstants.tgtSizeList).map(Label::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        fieldPosture.getItems().addAll(Arrays.stream(IConstants.postureList).map(Label::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        fieldTerr.getItems().addAll(Arrays.stream(IConstants.terrList).map(Label::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        loadDB();
        tableView.setItems(obs);

        //System.out.println( obs );

        ser.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ser());
        id.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().id());
        tgtName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().tgtName());
        tgtName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tgtName.setOnEditCommit(
                (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TgtModel, String> t) -> {

                    if (!t.getNewValue().trim().equals("")) {
                        t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setTgtName(t.getNewValue());
                        updateDB();
                    }
                    loadDB();
                });

        tgtSize.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().tgtSize());
        tgtSize.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(IConstants.tgtSizeList));
        tgtSize.setOnEditCommit(
                (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TgtModel, String> t) -> {
                    if (!t.getNewValue().trim().equals("")) {
                        t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setTgtSize(t.getNewValue());
                        updateDB();
                    }
                    loadDB();
                });

        tgtPosture.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().tgtPosture());
        tgtPosture.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(IConstants.postureList));
        tgtPosture.setOnEditCommit(
                (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TgtModel, String> t) -> {
                    if (!t.getNewValue().trim().equals("")) {
                        t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setTgtPosture(t.getNewValue());
                        updateDB();
                    }
                    loadDB();
                });

        terr.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().terr());
        terr.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(IConstants.terrList));
        terr.setOnEditCommit(
                (TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TgtModel, String> t) -> {
                    if (!t.getNewValue().trim().equals("")) {
                        t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setTerr(t.getNewValue());
                        updateDB();
                    }
                    loadDB();
                });

        setTableEditable();
    }

    private void setTableEditable() {
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getSelectionModel().cellSelectionEnabledProperty().set(true);
        tableView.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode().isLetterKey() || event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
                editFocusedCell();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT
                    || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                tableView.getSelectionModel().selectNext();
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                tableView.getSelectionModel().selectPrevious();
                event.consume();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void editFocusedCell() {
        final TablePosition<TgtModel, ?> focusedCell = tableView
                .focusModelProperty().get().focusedCellProperty().get();
        tableView.edit(focusedCell.getRow(), focusedCell.getTableColumn());
    }

    @FXML
    private void add() {
        Set<String> nameSet = obs.stream().map(s -> s.tgtName().getValue()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        System.out.println(nameSet);
        if (nameSet.contains(fieldTgtName.getText().trim())) {
            getErrorPopUp();
            return;
        }
        if (fieldTgtName.getText().trim().equals("")) return;
        if (fieldTgtSize.getValue() == null || fieldTgtSize.getValue().getText().trim().equals("")) return;
        if (fieldPosture.getValue() == null || fieldPosture.getValue().getText().trim().equals("")) return;
        if (fieldTerr.getValue() == null || fieldTerr.getValue().getText().trim().equals("")) return;

        TgtModel temp = new TgtModel(fieldTgtName.getText().trim(), fieldTgtSize.getValue().getText().trim(),
                fieldPosture.getValue().getText().trim(),
                fieldTerr.getValue().getText().trim());

        tgtDb.addTgt(temp);
        loadDB();

        fieldTgtName.clear();
        fieldTgtSize.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        fieldPosture.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        fieldTerr.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }

    private void loadDB() {
        obs.clear();
        obs.addAll(tgtDb.tgtList());
    }

    private void updateDB() {
        tgtDb.UpdateDb(obs);
    }

    @FXML
    private void deleteFromDb() {

        TgtModel tgt = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (tgt == null) return;
        tableView.getItems().removeAll(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

        tgtDb.deleteFromDb(tgt);
        updateDB();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your project structure doesn't seem to indicate a `tgtList` folder anywhere. Show the actual code you are using to load the images.

Comment: @James_D I have updated the structure for your reference. Thank you.

Comment: Post the code as well.

Comment: And, since the path it's trying to load from looks correct, you probably want to check the content of the jar file to see if `main.jpg` is included and is in the expected location. Use `jar -tf IFTAS.jar` from the command line (in the appropriate directory). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other

Comment: Thank you @James_D I have used WinRAR to view the inside contents of the jar. The image is where it should be. Still could not fix it.

Comment: That all looks correct. It's definitely `main.jpg`, not `Main.jpg`, or any other variation?

Comment: @James_D Yes, it is main.jpg. Do you think it could be an issue with the IntelliJ IDE? Should I try using NetBeans or Eclipse?

Comment: IDE makes no difference.

Comment: strip it down to a [mcve] - for your own sake: you don't need all the unrelated stuff to troubleshoot a resource you can't load for any reason ..

Comment: Although it is late, I have solved the problem. Could not identify the core problem but assuming it is an IDE issue of IntelliJ. Opened a new project and gradually added package by package and it works fine now.